# How to calculate the maximum PWM frequency of a MOSFET switch circuit?

Tags: pwm, mosfet-driver

How do you calculate the maximum PWM frequency of a P-channel MOSFET being used as a switch?

[image]

- The driver is a [PMD3001](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2005261505_Nexperia-PMD3001D-115_C458758.pdf) totem pole IC.
- The P-channel MOSFET is a [DMP3007](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1912111437_Diodes-Incorporated-DMP3007SPS-13_C397981.pdf).

Comment: is your load really a purely ohmic, 100Ω resistor? and how good is your Q1 cooled? Is your R1 fixed? I guess your component choices for D1 and Q1 are.

Comment: @MarcusMüller yes , keeping it simple for now, a high current resistive load. and the components are cooled very well. R1 can be swaped out for anyvalue if it helps increasing the max frequency.

Comment: "keeping it simple for now": That's OK, but it means any answer is probably meaningless once you use a real-world load.

Comment: Plus, you'll have to define what "cooled well" means, in numbers, e.g. in a thermal resistance °C/W; otherwise, it's impossible to tell how how your MOSFET gets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Determining the maximum frequency at which this circuit can operate isn't that easy.

However, there are some speed limiting factors we can have a look at:

How fast can we turn the MOSFET on and off? The MOSFET gate behaves somewhat similar to a capacitor. In the datasheet we see a value for "input capacitance" on page 2, this \$C_{in}\$ = 2.8 nF.

A current is needed to charge/discharge this gate capacitance. The maximum current which the PMD3001 can deliver is 1 A (yes, there's also a 2 A stated but that cannot be repeated like it is when using PWM).

Suppose the gate capacitance of the MOSFET is fully empty so 0 V and the supply voltage is 24 V. Now we want the driver to charge the gate as fast as possible so we pull the output of the driver to Ground. Assuming that the driver behaves like an ideal switch, there would be 24 V across R1. That means 24 V / 10 ohm = 2.4 A flowing. Oops! That's more than the PMD3001 can handle! You need to limit the current to 1 A. So we need R1 = 24 Ohm.

If you would use a 10 V supply, then 10 Ohm would be OK.

So we're charging a 2.8 nF capacitor with 1 A. If we then also use a supply of 10 V the charging will take approximately 28 ns. You want this charging to be a small part of one PWM cycle so let's assume that this 28 ns is only 1% of a complete cycle. Then the cycle time would be 100 x as large so 2800 ns. A repitition rate of 2800 ns means a frequency of 1/2800 ns = 357 kHz.

This is a simple "first order" calculation with lots of assumptions so there are no guarantees!

You would do better to put this circuit in a simulator (like LTSpice) and simulate it!

Then you would also discover that this circuit is not going to work properly!

Why is that? Let me draw the schematic on a transistor level:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFJ1HF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The PMD3001 you selected only contains an NPN and a PNP which are configured as a "totempole driver". Both transistors operate as emitter followers and that means they do not amplify the voltage.

To fully switch off your MOSFET you would need to apply the full supply voltage (5 V - 24 V) to its gate. This circuit cannot do that unless your PWM signal rises to the same voltage (5 V - 24 V).

If you would apply a PWM signal of 0 / 3.3 V then **the MOSFET will never be off**. That's not what you want I guess. I suggest that you find a more suitable driver.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but oh no so i have to place another transistor before the D1 so i can convert the 3.3v to Supply voltage. I noticed that the gate resistor will be subjected to the full driver current, will 1W rated even be enough?

Comment: *the gate resistor will be subjected to the full driver current, will 1W rated even be enough?* Theoretically the peak power in that resistor is 1A * 10 V = **10 W**! Furtunately, the power comes in small bursts so on average, the power is much less. How much: simulate the circuit and find out! Realize that if you use a "one transistor levelshifter" before driver D1, that might limit the maximum speed. If you want high speed, a dedicated gate driver chip might result in a faster circuit.

Answer (score 0):

The FET is rated for 1MHz with higher current R load.

Unidentified L/R =T1 and RC =T2 may affect recovery times rated at 0.35us for Toff.